# prepopulate form on godaddy

Tags: javascript, html, css, godaddy-api

I am currently trying to prepopulate the input box from the query in the url. I am not sure why it is not working.

I have tested the code on a live server in vs code, and this prepopulate function worked. However, when i tried putting the code on godaddy custom html section, the prepopulate function does not work. the query is called "referrer" in the code. Does anyone have any ideas where it could have went wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you. I have included the code for this function below.

```
 </form>

  <script>
    // JavaScript code goes here
    // Function to get query parameters from the URL
    function getQueryParameters() {
      var params = {};
      var search = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var keyValues = search.split('&');

      for (var i = 0; i < keyValues.length; i++) {
        var keyValue = keyValues[i].split('=');
        params[keyValue[0]] = decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
      }

      return params;
    }

    // Function to pre-populate the form field for "Where did you hear about us?"
    function prepopulateForm() {
      var params = getQueryParameters();
      var form = document.getElementById('signupForm');

      if (params.referrer) {
        document.getElementById('referrer').value = params.referrer;
      }
    }
//  code wrapped inside of smth that prevents read url. window.document
//
    // Call the prepopulateForm function when the page loads
    window.onload = prepopulateForm;

    // Function to show error message for email input
    function showError(elementId, message) {
      document.getElementById(elementId).innerText = message;
    }
```